# Veto execution if job is already executing

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I want to skip a job execution if another instance of the same job is already executing (if the same "JobDetail" is running). I know the annotation "@DisallowConcurrentExecution" avoid concurrent execution of the same job. But the downside is that when the job (a job that executes is a longer time then the periodicity of the trigger) finishes the job will be instantly re-executed. I want the job to be executed in the next schedule fire time.

## Example

> Job Implementation

```
public class LongJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            System.out.println("Executed: " + LocalDateTime.now().toString());
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> Scheduling

```
JobDetail job2 = JobBuilder.newJob(LongJob.class)
        .withIdentity("job2")
        .build();

Trigger trigger2 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
        .forJob(job2)
        .startNow()
        .withIdentity("job2-trigger")
        .withSchedule(
                CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/3 * * ? * *")
                        .withMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires())
        .build();
scheduler.scheduleJob(job2, trigger2);
```

> Expected output

```
Executed: 2016-02-18T10:11:15
Executed: 2016-02-18T10:11:21
Executed: 2016-02-18T10:11:27
Executed: 2016-02-18T10:11:33
```

> Output using @DisallowConcurrentExecution

```
Executed: 2016-02-18T10:11:15
Executed: 2016-02-18T10:11:20
Executed: 2016-02-18T10:11:25
Executed: 2016-02-18T10:11:30
```

## My Solution

I made a solution using Trigger Listeners, But I was wondering if there is a simpler one. In this approach I would have use a Listener Instance for each group of Trigger that fires the same job (I can solve my "bigger" problem using different trigger for different, avoiding the use of the same trigger for different jobs).

```
class CustomTriggerListener extends TriggerListenerSupport {

    private JobExecutionContext lastJobExecutionContext;

    @Override
    public boolean vetoJobExecution(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context) {
        boolean vetoExecution = false;
        if (lastJobExecutionContext == null) {
            lastJobExecutionContext = context;
        } else {
            boolean lastJobIsDone = lastJobExecutionContext.getJobRunTime() >= 0;

            if (lastJobIsDone) {
                lastJobExecutionContext = context;
            } else {
                vetoExecution = true;
            }
        }

        return vetoExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "CustomTriggerListener";
    }

}
```

Comment: You try and use some kind of semaphore and check that, i.e. when a job starts to run it raises the semaphore and removes it again after finishing. When a second job starts and sees the semaphore it stops immediately.

Comment: That could work as well, but I preferer the CustromTrigger approach. But the CustomTrigger wont work with triggers that fire multiples jobs, the semaphore solution would